# Find a value of n so that partial sum is greater equal to 10

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Given :  $$ S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \text{ , } T_{n} = \int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx $$
> Find a value of $n$ so that $S_{n} \geq 10$.

My Approach:
Its easy to see that $S_{n} > T_{n}$, and we know
$$ T_{n} = \int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} dx = [\ln(x)]_{x=1}^{x=n+1}=(\ln(n+1)-\ln(1))=\ln(n+1)
$$
Then we solve $\ln(n+1) \geq 10$, we have $n > 22026$.

My question is:

1. Is my approach right?
2. Since the question is from a friend of mine, and he showed me the "solution" from his professor, but I could not understand, I may need some explanation.
   The solution is:

> Condensation would have given $ 10 = 1 + \frac{N}{2}$, at $N = 18$, so we need
> $n = 2^N = 2^{18} = 262144.$

Many Thanks!

Comment: Your approach is fine.  Your friend's value is over ten times higher.  Although that value of $n$ solves the problem as stated, your lower one does, too.  I don't understand your friend's "solution" either.

Comment: @RossMillikan True, i don't understand either, my friend said its from a past paper in his uni

Comment: Take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test It's the idea used in the solution

Comment: What do you mean by $n=2^n=2^{18}$? We always have $n<2^n$.

Comment: @Gary sry, should be $n=2^N$, fixed now

Comment: @Cassio Thank you its really helpful!

Comment: The equality $\sum \frac 1{2^k} = \sum \binom Nk \frac 1{2^k}$ isn't right. Notice $\sum \frac 1k \geq \sum \frac { 1}{2^k}$ is true, but not good enough for this problem. Because $\sum \frac 1{ 2^k}$ converges to 2, so you cannot prove that $\sum \frac 1k  > 10$ with this lower bound

Comment: Thank you for spotting the error and, ill fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By condensation, I think the solution means the idea behind Cauchy's condensation test. Let $S_n = \displaystyle \sum_{k= 1} ^n f(k)$, where $f(k) = \dfrac 1k$. We notice $f$ is decreasing. Take a look in $S_n$ when $n$ is a power of 2
$$S_1 = f(1)$$
$$S_2 = f(1) + f(2)$$
$$S_4 = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4)  > f(1) + f(2) + f(4) + f(4)$$
Here we changed $f(3)$ for $f(4)$, since $f(3) > f(4)$.
$$S_8 = f(1) + f(2) + \cdots +f(8) > f(1) + f(2) + 2f(4) + 4f(8)$$
Here we changed $f(3)$ for $f(4)$ and $f(5),f(6), f(7)$ for $f(8)$. And so on. More generally we have:

$$S_{2^N} > f(1) + f(2) + 2f(4) + 4f(8) + 8f(16) + \cdots + 2^{N-1} f(2^N)$$

Since $f(k) = \dfrac 1k$ we have:
$$f(1) + f(2) + 2f(4) + 4f(8) + 8f(16) + \cdots + 2^{N-1} f(2^N) = $$ $$= 1+ \dfrac 12 + \dfrac 24 + \dfrac 48 + \dfrac 8{16} + \cdots + \dfrac{2^{N-1}}{2^N}$$
$$ = 1 + \underbrace{ \dfrac 12 + \dfrac 12 + \cdots  + \dfrac 12}_{N} = 1+\dfrac N2$$

Then $S_{2^N} > 1 + \dfrac N2$. Using $N = 18$ we get  $S_{2^{18}} >1 + \dfrac{18}{2} = 10$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i think this is easier to understand!

Answer (score 2):

Using harmonic numbers
$$S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} =H_n$$ and you want to solve for $n$ the equation
$$H_n=k$$ Using the asymptotics
$$H_n=\gamma +\log (n)+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ you have as a very first approximation
$$k=\gamma +\log (n)\quad \implies \quad n\sim e^{k-\gamma } \tag 1$$ Using one more term
$$k=\gamma +\log (n)+\frac{1}{2 n}\quad \implies \quad  n\sim -\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{\gamma -k}\right)} \tag 2$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

For $k=10$, $(1)$ will give, as a real, $n_1=12366.968$ and $(2)$ will give $n_2=12366.468$ while the "exact" solution is $n=12366.470$.

Checking
$$H_{12366}=9.999962148 \qquad \text{and} \qquad H_{12367}=10.00004301$$

I do not understand your friend's solution (which is obviously wrong).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The friend's solution is *not* wrong. The goal is to find *a* number, not the smallest such.